# Extending Twig with new function. Can I access exisiting functions?

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm extending Twig using this:

```
namespace Acme\Bundle\MyBundle\Twig;

use Twig_SimpleFunction;

class LinkGenerator extends \Twig_Extension
{

    public function getFunctions() {

        return array(
            new Twig_SimpleFunction('link', function($param) {
                return "TEST " . $param;
            })
        );

    }

    public function getName() {

        return "link";

    }

}
```

It works fine. Using {{ link(2) }} returns 'TEST 2'.

For demo purposes, I want to simply append the query sting ?link=1 to what this would render if using the 'url' Twig function.

So code might look like this:

```
new Twig_SimpleFunction('link', function($param) {

    //render exactly how this would look if using the Twig 'url' function
    $url = $this->runFunction('url', $params);

    //append the query string
    $url .= "?link=1";

    return $url;

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the DIC to inject dependencies in to your Twig extension.

I would try injecting the `RoutingExtension` class provided by Symfony2's TwigBundle.

---

(untested)

DIC config:

```
<service id="my.link_generator.twig.extension" class="Path\To\My\Templating\Twig\LinkGeneratorExtension">
    <argument type="service" id="twig.extension.routing"/>
    <tag name="twig.extension" />
</service>
```

LinkGeneratorExtension.php

```
class LinkGenerator extends \Twig_Extension
{
    protected $routingExt;

    public function __construct(RoutingExtension $routingExt)
    {
        $this->routingExt = $routingExt;
    }

    public function getLink($foo)
    {
        // ...
        $this->routingExt->getUrl(...);
    }
}
```